# Pygame, pygame_menu - close after start and video system not initialized error

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying make Simon game. I'm beginner in programming.
I have problem when i start program first time the menu starts. When i click on play and another play in submenu it starts main loop and game works properly.
when i close the window it gives me an error:

***pygame.display.flip()
error: video system not initialized***

When i start progam second time the window will start but it closes immediately without error message.

And so it is still around:
Start first time -> Start and with close error.
Start second time -> Close window without error.
I checked some posts I checked some posts but it did'nt work.

```
import pygame as game
import pygame_menu as game_menu

print(game.font.get_fonts())


game.init()

game.font.init()

game.mixer.init()


WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500


FPS = 60


window = game.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

game.display.set_caption("Simon v1.0")

#FONTS

Font = game.font.SysFont("Arial", 85)
mainFont = game_menu.font.FONT_MUNRO
titleFont = game_menu.font.FONT_8BIT
titleBar = game_menu.widgets.MENUBAR_STYLE_UNDERLINE
fontScore = game.font.SysFont("Arial", 35)
FontLower = game.font.SysFont("Arial", 20)

#Width for center
# nameWidth, _ = Font.size("SIMON")
pressWidth, _ = Font.size("Press space to start")
overWidth, _ = Font.size("Gameover")
#MENU THEME
menuTheme = mytheme = game_menu.Theme(background_color=(0, 0, 0, 0),
                title_background_color=(255, 255, 255, 255),
                widget_padding = 15,
                widget_font = mainFont,
                widget_font_size = 20,
                widget_font_color = (255, 255, 255),
                title_font = titleFont,
                title_bar_style = titleBar,
                title_offset = (0, -10),
                widget_box_border_width = 100,
                title_font_color = (209, 212, 161))

#Player name
playerName = ""

#colors
radius = 100
redCircle = (140,0,0)
blueCircle = (0,0,140)
yellowCircle = (140,140,0)
greenCircle = (0,140,0)

run = True
gameOver = False
gameState = 0
score = 0

def main():

    global run, gameState, colorR, colorG, colorB


    clock = game.time.Clock()  
    draw()
    while run == True:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in game.event.get():

            if event.type == game.QUIT:

               run = False
    game.quit() 

def draw():
    global gameOver, overWidth
    
    window.fill((0,0,0))
    
    if gameState == 0:
        textPress = fontScore.render("Press space to start ", 1, (255,255,255))
        window.blit(textPress, (WIDTH/2 - pressWidth/2,50))
    
    if gameOver:
        textGameOver = mainFont.render("Gameover", 1, (255,255,255))
        centerTitle = textGameOver.get_rect(center=(WIDTH/2,120))
        window.blit(textGameOver, centerTitle)
        
        textFinScore = fontScore.render("Your score is: " + str(score), 1, (255,255,255))
        centerTitle = textFinScore.get_rect(center=(WIDTH/2,200))
        window.blit(textFinScore, centerTitle)
        
        textRestart = FontLower.render("Press space for restart", 1, (255,255,255))
        centerTitle = textRestart.get_rect(center=(WIDTH/2,300))
        window.blit(textRestart, centerTitle)
        
        textExit = FontLower.render("Press esc for exit from game", 1, (255,255,255))
        centerTitle = textExit.get_rect(center=(WIDTH/2,335))
        window.blit(textExit, centerTitle)
        
    else:
        game.draw.circle(window, redCircle, [(WIDTH/2), 240], radius, 40, draw_top_right = True)
        game.draw.circle(window, blueCircle, [(WIDTH/2), 250], radius, 40, draw_bottom_right = True)
        game.draw.circle(window, greenCircle, [(WIDTH/2)-10, 240], radius, 40, draw_top_left = True)
        game.draw.circle(window, yellowCircle, [(WIDTH/2)-10, 250], radius, 40, draw_bottom_left = True)  
        draw_score()
        
    game.display.update() 
    game.display.flip()
    
def draw_score():
    textScore = fontScore.render("Score: " + str(score), 1, (255,255,255))
    window.blit(textScore, (20,0))    

def save_name(name):
    global playerName
    playerName = name
    print(playerName)

def mainMenu():
    global top,menu,credi,play,topMenu
    
    Cred = "Created by: "
    
    menu = game_menu.Menu(300, 400, 'Simon', theme = menuTheme)
    credi = game_menu.Menu(300, 400, 'Simon', onclose = None, theme = menuTheme)
    play = game_menu.Menu(300, 400, 'Simon', onclose = None, theme = menuTheme)
    topMenu = game_menu.Menu(300, 400, 'Simon', onclose = None, theme = menuTheme)
    #Main menu
    menu.add.button("Play", play)
    menu.add.button("Top score")
    menu.add.button("Settings")
    menu.add.button("Credits", credi)
    menu.add.button("Quit", game_menu.events.EXIT)
    #Credit submenu
    credi.add_label(Cred, max_char = 0, font_size = 20)
    credi.add.button("Back", game_menu.events.BACK)
    
    #Play submenu
    play.add_label("Type your name", font_size = 20)
    play.add.text_input("Name : ", default = '', input_underline = "_", maxchar = 14, onchange = save_name, onreturn = save_name)
    play.add.button("Play", main)
    play.add.button("Back", game_menu.events.BACK)
    menu.mainloop(window)

mainMenu()
```

Sorry for my bad english.
And Thanks for your tips

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: how do you run it? Did you try to kill it? Did you use `pygame.quit()`

Comment: when you close window then `main()` runs `pygame.quit()` but next it goes back to `mainMenu` which still runs `mainloop()` to draw menu and it still to try to use `flip()` to display menu. You could use `exit()` after `pygame.quit()` to exit program. Or you should check if `menu` has function to stop `mainloop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you close window then `main()` runs `game.quit()` which close access to video but next it goes back to `mainMenu` which still runs `mainloop()` to draw menu and it still tries to access video display menu. And this makes problem

You could use `exit()` after `game.quit() to exit program.

```
        if event.type == game.QUIT:
           game.quit() 
           exit()
```

Comment: Yes it works. Thank you. But there is still second problem. when i start program first time works everything properly and when i start program second time window show up for maybe 2 second and closes. This is repeats. I think that it will be something with this: `play.add.button("Play", main)`, because when i delete main from this the program will start everytime and works

Comment: I have no idea. On my computer it always works. If you run it in any IDE then problem could be IDE. I run it always directly in console/terminal. And when I run it in editor then it always start new console so it doesn't have older processes. I test it on Linux Mint 20, Python 3.8.5, pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14), pygame-menu 4.0.4

Comment: I run it in Spyder. I will try terminal. 
Okay thanks you